# How to allocate static storage dynamically in c?

Tags: c, list, memory-management, dynamic, static

In a recursive method to group the external nodes of a tree, i need to allocate memory dynamically inside that function.But the statement

```
static node* ext_node = malloc (sizeof(node));
```

is not working, and compiler gives error,which says

> initializer element is not constant.

In short i want to ask that how can i use the `static` keyword with a pointer in a recursive call when the memory to which the pointer is pointing is dynamically acquired?

I require this because, when it is required to add more element in the list, the method `insert_to_end (node*)` will take the responsibility of allocating the storage for new node, so with this i can create `list` of any length and that is too with exact memory requirement.

**But how to achieve this in c language?**

Comment: Please clarify your question, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @iharob ok i am editing it.

Comment: Now it's not clear what **is not working** means.

Comment: can we have node detail ?

Comment: The initialization of a static scope variable has to be a constant expression.

Comment: It is not an usual thing to mix a `static`-storage pointer variable with dynamic allocations. When you create a NEW node, you MUST allocate memory **exclusively** for it. You should NOT reuse memory, otherwise you'll be **overwriting** an old element. Ditch the `static` and be happy. If you still want the static pointer, you can have it, but you should declare it and later initialize it, in another step. You will save 4 or 8 bytes of stack during the function prologue, which is negligible in most cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that *in general* using `static` in a recursive function is a mistake (and is also thread-unsafe). It is almost always better to pass required data into the function via parameters.

However, if you insist, you can do it this way:

```
static node* ext_node;
if (ext_node == NULL) ext_node = malloc (sizeof(node));
```

> That error doesn't make sense

A C compiler will initialize static variables *at compile time* (this requirement was relaxed in C++, and your original code will compile with a C++ compiler).

You can do this:

```
static int foo;  // default initialized to 0
static int bar = 42;
```

but not this:

```
static int baz = some_func();  // Error: at compile time the value to put into baz is not known.
```

Comment: I didn't even see `static` since it's quite unexpected in this situation, good point.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do so, just split it into 2 operations, like this:

```
static node *ext_node;

if (ext_node == NULL)
    ext_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

But it looks like flawed design for me (usually using `static` variables inside functions  is a bad practice -- makes function not [reentrable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)).

Why don't pass this `ext_node` to your function, as a parameter? And why are you need to do this variable `static` in the first place?

Comment: This code is semantically very different from the original. In particular, it will leak memory on each iteration.

Comment: How did you figured that? It **will not** leak, if you will free this memory after using it. Read my edit.

Comment: Or you could initialize to NULL(should happen by default, it being a static type), and then allocate after a check. If we *have* to do this, I don't see a "cleaner" way.

Comment: Yes, it will fo to BSS section, hence it will be NULL by default. I just showed basic concept why is author having compile error. The whole approach is bad as for me, so I explained it just after the code. I edited my code though, thanks.